# Automapper и IDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, automapper

Доброго времени суток! У меня возник такой вопрос. Допустим у меня есть бд, в которой есть таблицы вида:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
   Id int,
   Name nvarchar(100),
   BarId int
)

CREATE TABLE Bar
(
    Id int,
    Text nvarchar(100)
)
```

Причем  столбец BarId в таблице Foo  - это foreign key на Bar.Id. Затем я запрос вида

```
SELECT f., b.Id as BarId, b.Name as BarName
FROM Foo f
JOIN Bar b ON b.Id = f.BarId
```

Результаты этого запроса я получаю в IDataReader. Для их отображения у меня есть классы

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Для получения данных из ридера я использую Automapper. Вот так:

```
public class DataReaderConverter<TDto> : ITypeConverter<IDataReader, TDto> where TDto : new
{
    // код этого метода немного упрощен, но в целом всё так и работает
    public TDto Convert(IDataReader source, TDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
            destination = new TDto();

        typeof(TDto).GetProperties().ToList()
            .ForEach(property => property.SetValue(destination, source[property.Name]));
    }
}


cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, Foo>().ConvertUsing(new DataReaderConverter<Foo>());
```

И тут возникает проблема. Дело в том, что если запрос обычный, без джойнов, то `DataReaderConverter` вполне успешно всё маппит. Но в моём запросе есть джойн с таблицей Bar, и я не могу сопоставить свойство `Bar` со столбцами `BarId` и `BarName`, Есть ли какая-то возможность заставить Automapper понимать, как нужно маппить свойства-классы из столбцов ридера?

Comment: Может, лучше использовать такие microORM, как Dapper/PetaPoco/Massive? Они как раз, по сути, являются мапперами из датаридера в объекты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне нужен именно маппер из DataReader'a. Переписывать логику работы с данными на ORM (даже микро) нет ни времени ни возможности